# siunitx \num giving thousands space for 5 digits but not for 4 digits

Tags: siunitx

I have a table with numbers that are right aligned. I changed them to use `\num{}` to try and improve the output. But it seems that `\num{}` adds a thousands separator space for 5 digit numbers but not for four digits, so now my table looks worse than with no spaces at all. How can I make `\num{}` add the same space for 4 and 5 digit numbers?

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\num{10000}
\num{1000}
```

The output I am getting is something like:

```
10 000
  1000
```

When I would like:

```
10 000
 1 000
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Check the documentation.

Comment: I have looked and cannot find it. I was hoping someone here would be able to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the `group-minimum-digits` option.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4}

\begin{document}

\num{10000}

\num{1000}

\end{document}
```

Grouping rules are not applied to numbers with fewer digits.  By default this is `5`, which prevents the reformatting of four digit numbers.